# Snowflake's `try_to_geography` raises an error instead of returning null

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geojson

I am trying to run a query in Snowflake to convert a GeoJSON object into Snowflake's baked-in [geospatial data types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-geospatial.html):

```
SELECT id, -- some other columns
       TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY(raw_row) -- raw row is my GeoJSON object
FROM ...
```

The Snowflake documentation for `TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY` says:

> Parses an input and returns a value of type GEOGRAPHY.
>
> This function is essentially identical to TO_GEOGRAPHY except that it returns NULL when TO_GEOGRAPHY would issue an error.

However when I run the query I get the following very uninformative error (no mention of column, record or even SQL line that produced the error):

> Failed to cast variant value "null" to OBJECT

I pinpointed the `TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY` to be the cause since the query works if I comment that line. Shouldn't Snowflake return `NULL` in this case? How can I fix the problem? And if there's faulty data in my table, is there any way for me to find the rows where the function fails (it has 9 digits row count, I can't do it manually)?

Answer (score 1):

Is your `raw_row` of `VARIANT` type or `VARCHAR`?

The Snowflake documentation for `TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY` also mentions (emphasis mine)

> <variant_expression>
>
> The argument **must** be an OBJECT in GeoJSON format.

So if you try to parse a variant value that is not an "OBJECT in GeoJson format" it will indeed raise an error:

```
SELECT
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('' :: VARCHAR), -- NULL
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('' :: VARIANT), -- error!
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('{"geometry": null, "type": "Feature"}' :: VARCHAR), -- NULL
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('{"geometry": null, "type": "Feature"}' :: VARIANT); -- error!
```

However you can argue the documentation is not all that clear on this issue, and there are some cases where they both act the same. Surprisingly:

```
SELECT
    -- just removing {"type": "Feature"} from the error above
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('{"geometry": null}' :: VARIANT), -- NULL

    -- just removing {"geometry": null} from the error above
    -- a Feature without "geometry" and "properties" is ill-defined by the spec
    TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY('{"type": "Feature"}' :: VARIANT); -- NULL
```

So it's unclear if it's a bug in Snowflake or if it's intended behavior. Note `TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY` will work as expected if the object is a valid GeoJSON format but the geography itself is invalid. For example a polygon where edges cross each other will return null for the `TRY_` version but fail with an error with `TO_GEOGRAPHY`.

**How to fix it**: the simplest way is to convert the variant column to varchar, which is a bit silly but it works. You can then query the NULL values produced and check the GeoJSON values that produced an error, hoping it's not that many to manually check them.

Comment: Self-answering because I found the fix in about an hour of debugging. Still accepting new answers for a better solution and possibly a way to pinpoint the faulty data.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to convert the object under key **geometry**.

The Geojson may have other keys, such as **feature** and **properties**. Your table can be designed with these 1st level keys as columns (in my case I just drop **feature**). In case the **geometry** is null, **TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY** will return **NULL**. In case it is one of the others, there is no need to do a conversion (just use type **OBJECT** or **VARIANT**).

The problem seems to be getting a **GEOGRAPHY** data from a non-viable object as source (e.g., having the object under **geometry** as null).